# CPU / GPU usage are both below 100% - what is bottlenecking my game?

Tags: opengl, performance, profiling

I've been developing a C++ OpenGL game for the last couple of months.

A few weeks ago I was profiling the game and I noticed that the GPU usage was almost at 100% (with the framerate uncapped). I added a new feature and the GPU usage capped at arround 35% (also with the framerate unlocked).

At first I thought that this was about CPU bottleneck, but the CPU was also around 35% usage.

I was expecting the framerate to lower after that update (and it did, from about 2000 to 600) but I thought that the CPU / GPU usage would still be high.

Having the GPU usage this low makes me think that I should be getting more FPS.

Is this behaviour normal, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: When you check the CPU usage, make sure you check all cores separately. Maybe one of your cores is at 100% while the others are idle.

Comment: There are also other possible resource bottlenecks, like memory access, pcie lanes or file IO which can cause both gpu and cpu to stall. Did you rule those out?

Comment: @Vaillancourt , that was it. One of the CPU cores is performing at 95% while the others are lower. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! You're free to write an answer to your own question if you want :)

Answer (score 1):

As @Vaillancourt pointed out, even though the CPU wasn't getting high usage percentage, one of it's cores was. I guess it's time to improve the multi-threading of my game!